# laravel split table in two table for one model

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a one model car and table cars. In the table cars I have a lot of filed that are required to be there.

Is there any way to split this table by the filed so f1,f2,f3 go in table 'cars' and f6, f7, f8 in 'cars2'.

My goal is to at the end not to write two query for the two tables. Is this possible with eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I would not recommend the idea of splitting the table.
Because **cars** and **cars2** would make the DB a redundant one , thereby causing a lot of ambiguity for coders to come.

However, I would recommend the use of join queries to gracefully access all the data needed from the 2 tables that your planning to use , using only a single query.